# Python: How can I read in the characters from a line in a file and convert them to floats and strs, depending on if they are numbers or letters?

Tags: python, input

I have a file that looks like:

```
1 1 C C 1.9873 2.347 3.88776

1 2 C Si 4.887 9.009 1.21
```

I would like to read in the contents of the file, line-by-line. When I only had numbers on the lines I used:

```
for line in readlines(file):
    data = map(float, line.split)
```

But this only works when all the elements of line.split are numbers. How can I make it store the letters as strings and the numbers as floats?

Comment: Why not to try with 'try/exept'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for line in infile:
    data = [x if x.isalpha() else float(x) for x in line.split()]
```

There will be issues if your data contains fields that are neither alphabetic nor valid floating-point numbers (for example, "A1").  Your data doesn't seem to have these from what you said, but if it does, the `try/except` approach suggested by Igor would probably suit better.

I would probably use a more generic function that can be given the types to try, however:

```
def tryconvert(value, *types):
    for t in types:
        try:
            return t(value)
        except (ValueError, TypeError):
            continue
    return value

for line in infile:
    data = [tryconvert(x, int, float) for x in line.split()]
```

This will convert anything that be converted to an integer to an `int`, failing that it will try `float`, and then finally it just gives up and returns the original value, which we know will be a string. (If we didn't know it was a string we could just stick `str` on the end of our call to `tryconvert()`.)

Comment: Thanks this seems to work! This website is incredibly helpful

Comment: @Igor: That's only a problem if it actually appears in the data. :-)

Comment: Worse, "C12".isalpha() is false. Igor's solution is much more robust; it literally says "if you can parse a field as a float, do so, otherwise treat it as a string".

Comment: @kindall: bulletproof logic :)

Answer (score 9):

```
$ cat 1.py
def float_or_str(x):
  try:
     return float(x)
  except ValueError:
     return x

line = '1 1 C C 1.9873 2.347 3.88776'
print map(float_or_str, line.split())

$python 1.py
[1.0, 1.0, 'C', 'C', 1.9873, 2.347, 3.88776]
```

Comment: Don't use a bare except. That's very bad style.

Comment: Ehhhhhh, I'd let it pass in this case. It's bad style because it makes it hard to figure out what went wrong and where, but in this case there's only one place that something could go wrong and only one thing you want to do regardless of what went wrong.

Comment: @asmeurer: I don't think that it is a bad style in the case

Comment: To quote PEP 8: "A good rule of thumb is to limit use of bare 'except' clauses to two cases:

If the exception handler will be printing out or logging the traceback; at least the user will be aware that an error has occurred.
If the code needs to do some cleanup work, but then lets the exception propagate upwards with raise. try...finally can be a better way to handle this case.". So it is bad style in this case.

Comment: @asmeurer: fixed anyway. Thank you for the hint!

Answer (score -1):

You can use methods str.isalpha(), str.isalphanum(), str.isdigit to decide if your string is a number or not.

Comment: Not always. For example: ".".isalpha() == False